# Ignore certain information when loading a local file in the DB?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to ignore certain information when loading a local file in the DB?

Example: I have a file with 2 columns "PHONE" and "VALIDATED" where a column of "VALIDATED" receives the status of 'YES' or 'NO'.

[image: Table Data]

As I don't need negative cases, I wanted to ignore them to save space and improve query times.

Is there any way for me to load only phones where `VALIDATED = YES`?

DB: MYSQL 6.3

Import: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Comment: Please translate the title of the question as well.

Comment: Q: Is there a way to ignore certain information when loading a local file in the DB?  A: Sure.  But not with "LOAD".  Your best bet is to write a program (any language: Java, Python, C, C#, etc, etc) that 1) parses your input file, 2) writes to MySql

Comment: Paul, thanks for the feedback, I will research how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crossposting a translation of [my original answer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/491315/100) at [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com):

It's always possible to load all data to a temporary table and later copy only desired rows to the destination table.

Assuming a table called `contacts`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE contacts_temp LIKE contacts;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'my_file' INTO TABLE contacts_temp;
INSERT INTO contacts (phones, validated, dt_imp)
SELECT phone, validated, dt_imp
  FROM contacts_temp 
 WHERE validated = 'YES';
-- drop statement is only useful if you are planning to keep the
-- current session open
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE contacts_temp;
```

Comment: Hi Anthony, I will test this process. Thanks for the tip!